# Duplicate records found on fetch API using criteria builder

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, paging

I had a problem with getting **duplicate records** while using criteria builder in the fetch API call for the parent object data.

**Scenario**: ***Fetch All parent_obj values sort by child_obj.name & parent_obj.description***

**Query 1:**

```
select parent_obj.id, .. 
from parent_obj 
inner join child_obj on parent_obj.id = child_obj.id 
where 1=1 
group by parent_obj.id, child_obj.name 
order by child_obj.name asc, parent_obj.description asc
limit 15 offset 15;
```

**Query 2:**

```sql
select parent_obj.id, .. 
from parent_obj 
inner join child_obj on parent_obj.id = child_obj.id 
where 1=1 
group by parent_obj.id, child_obj.name 
order by child_obj.name asc, parent_obj.description asc
limit 15 offset 30;
```

In the *Query1* return, the 15 records with the values contain ids are **16, 17** to 30. Next Query2 return, the next 15 records but the records contains the ***duplicate value*** as **16 & 17** in the list.

**Note**: If I remove the `order by` from the query I can get the distinct values from parent_obj.

Database results for getting parent_obj.id:

**Query 1:**

```
id1_2_ |      name       | description  
--------+-----------------+--------------
   1638 | Adidas          | Nvbnbvn
   1624 | Adidas          | Nvbnbvn
   1623 | Adidas          | Nvbnbvn at
   1636 | Adidas          | Sddsfdsfdsfd
   1647 | Adidas          | Sdfsdf
   1504 | Adidas          | Sdfsdv
   1508 | Adidas          | Shirt
   1661 | Adidas          | Trainers
   1537 | Adidas          | Trainers
   1646 | Adidas          | Ttdhd
   1500 | Adidas          | Yellow wear
   1651 | Avec les filles | Hgfhgjyg
   1657 | BUFFALO         | Hmgmhgjjh
   1652 | BUFFALO         | Hmgmhgjjh
   1656 | BUFFALO         | Hmgmhgjjh
(15 rows)
```

**Query 2:**

```
 id1_2_ |   name   |     description      
--------+----------+----------------------
   1655 | BUFFALO  | Hmgmhgjjh
   1654 | BUFFALO  | Hmgmhgjjh
   1652 | BUFFALO  | Hmgmhgjjh
   1656 | BUFFALO  | Hmgmhgjjh
    484 | BURBERRY | Classic Camel
    483 | BURBERRY |  Red Check Scarf
    542 | CASTAÑER | Lurex Frayed Wedges
    504 | Chanel   | Polarized Sunglasses
    533 | CHLOÉ    | Faye Shoulder Bag
    534 | CHLOÉ    | Guipure Dress
    535 | CHLOÉ    | Rubie Sunglasses
    536 | CHLOÉ    | Sonnie Sneaker
    537 | CHLOÉ    | Susanna Boots
   1373 | CLUSE    | La Boheme Mesh
    469 | DIOR     | Dior Color Quake 1
(15 rows)
```

The above results contain the ids of **1652 & 1656** which is having the same name and same description.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So without group by keyword, i'll get redundant data

Comment: Please provide some example data as it exists in the database. What is the cardinality between parent and child? is it 1:1?

Comment: Why is this tagged as [criteria-api]? It just seems to be plain SQL

Comment: @JensSchauder updated sample data.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can u tell me the exact query for the above scenario?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name there is an `order by` in addition to the `group by`.

Comment: I was looking for the data as it exists in the tables not in the query result. Also for the results what are the respective values in the `child_obj.name` column?

Comment: @JensSchauder updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199055/discussion-between-jens-schauder-and-dwaynejohn).

Comment: @JensSchauder any updates?

Comment: What I wrote in the chat

Comment: @JensSchauder I replied to that above discussion chat

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't include all group by columns in the ordering.
Therefore you get rows that are not distinguished by the ordering, i.e. their respective order depends on the access path chosen by the database and essentially random.

This result in rows included in multiple pages and probably others not being included at at all.

In order to fix this have all columns of the group by clause appear in your order by clause, for example by adding the ones that aren't included at the end.